# Homebrew cannot find gcc

Tags: gcc, homebrew

I'm having trouble getting homebrew to work on Lion.  For some reason, it is picking up clang rather than gcc.

```
==> Upgrading gnutls
...
checking for gcc...
/usr/bin/clang checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

'brew doctor' says:

```
We couldn't detect gcc 4.2.x. Some formulae require this compiler. NOTE: Versions of XCode newer than 4.2 don't include gcc 4.2.x.
```

NOTE: I have already installed command line tools from XCode, including gcc.

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc -v
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
```

How can I force brew to use gcc?

Answer (score 12):

After Xcode 4.2, Apple stopped distributing gcc with Xcode. Instead, they distribute llvm-gcc (and clang), which are *not* gcc. You can see this with gcc -v, like you did: it shows `LLVM build`.

In order to use gcc, you will have to compile it yourself. There is a homebrew formula for this, but you will have to tap homebrew/dupes with `brew tap homebrew/dupes`.

Note that as of today, the gcc formula doesn't work if compiled with clang. You have to install it with `brew install --use-llvm gcc`.

Also note that Homebrew explicitly search for gcc-4.2. You will have to create a symlink for Homebrew to find gcc.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I tried 'brew tap', but my version of brew was too old for this new feature, and 'brew upgrade' is how I got to the error in my original question, so I was stuck.  I ended up solving my problem my uninstalling brew (see [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ/1ef6c2cf55db89252949c7bb2908abe093a3414a)), then reinstalling (see [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation)).  I also had to do some extra steps before re-installing, because I had unwisely installed brew as root, e.g. "sudo rm /usr/local/.git".  In the end, I didn't need a new gcc.

Comment: @ishmael That's the difference between `brew update` (Homebrew itself) and `brew upgrade` (formulas).

Comment: For me, --use-llvm will error when make bootstrap. `brew install --use-gcc gcc48` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Yosemite watch this video, it'll prompt you for XCode right from the command-prompt when you install Homebrew

http://dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/218

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when this changed, but Apple command line tools now include gcc and clang executables:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ which clang
/usr/bin/clang

$ clang -v
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

You can get it by running:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```